# how to delete whole datagridview and readd it without duplicates?

Tags: c#

This is my first time working with C#. I am trying to create a Datagridview that I can remove all the rows from the Table with one button click called Terminate All and then add it back to the default setting with one button called Reset but when I Click reset it adds a duplicate row of buttons in my datagrid. The       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) contains the code for the Reset button and the if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Terminate") contains the code for the Terminate all.
 Can anyone tell me how to remove the duplicate buttons on the end of my datagridview?

```
namespace Dispatcher_2._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();


        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Table.Columns.Add("PID", typeof(int));
            Table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            Table.Columns.Add("Priority", typeof(int));
            Table.Rows.Add(91, "Current Process", 0);
            Table.Rows.Add(92, "Ready", 23);
            Table.Rows.Add(95, "Ready", 22);
            Table.Rows.Add(93, "Ready", 28);
            Table.Rows.Add(94, "Ready", 44);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

            Btn.Name = "Time Slice";
            Btn.Text = "Time Slice";

            Btn1.Name = "Block";
            Btn1.Text = "Block";

            Btn2.Name = "Terminate";
            Btn2.Text = "Terminate";
            Btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            Btn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            Btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn1);  
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn2);

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table.Clear();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table.Rows.Add(91, "Current Process", 0);
            Table.Rows.Add(92, "Ready", 23);
            Table.Rows.Add(95, "Ready", 22);
            Table.Rows.Add(93, "Ready", 28);
            Table.Rows.Add(94, "Ready", 44);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Table;
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn1 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Btn2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

            Btn.Text = "Time Slice";
            Btn1.Text = "Block";
            Btn2.Text = "Terminate";
            Btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            Btn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            Btn2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn1);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Btn2);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Time slice")
            {

            }
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Block")
            {       
                int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].SetValues(new Random().Next(50, 100), "Blocked", "-1");
            }
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Terminate")
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table.Rows.Add(new Random().Next(50, 100), "Ready", textBox1.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are just clearing the table not removing columns from the datagridview.

Comment: I tried removing columns before and it left the three headers for the button columns and then when I clicked to add them back in it put the 3 button rows at the start of the grid and moved the values to the last three columns. So basically it switched the right side with the left side of the grid.

Comment: If number of columns and order of them does not change then you should not add them back. Just refresh the data of the table and rebind it to the gridview

Comment: And how would I do that? That is the reason why I am asking I have tried a bunch of different things and none of them have worked so far.

Comment: dataGridView1.Refresh();?

Comment: and then??//////

Comment: In button2_click remove code of adding new columns to grid view. Just add new rows to the datatable and bind it to grid view.

Comment: I got it to work by doing as you said I just put in the table without the columns and added refresh but if I click the button a second time it adds a second set of the original six columns. I guess I need to put in some kind of  if else statement to prevent it from printing twice?

Comment: I got it all working correctly now thanks for your help